# What similarity measure to use when preferences are involved?

Tags: similarities, matching

The question can be best understood with a problem statement. Assuming there is a professor and a student, I want to find out the compatibility of them working together on a project. Say I have the following attributes/qualities of each:

| Weightage | Student | Prof |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50% | Computer Science (Major) | Chemical Engineering |
| 25% | English, French, Spanish (Languages spoken) | English |
| 15% | Algos (Interests) | Algos, Biotech |
| 10% | France (Location) | U.K |

What similarity measure/index/coefficient would suite such a scenario where weights come into play? While I am inclined to use a something like Jaccard or Overlap Coefficient and simply multiply by the weightage, I am unsure of whether that would be an efficient way. Is there a better approach?

Comment: I would look into the math behind how dating websites match up partners. I would expect the student and professor to have a different relationship and for the important facets of that relationship to differ from a romantic relationship, but the idea of compatibility is present in both.

Comment: @Dave Agreed, its very similar to how those work. In-fact I started there. Most use propitiatory algos. The closest thing I came to what modern sites use is bi-partite graph edge weighting.